# How to reach a boundary point as specified by user from origin , random walk simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am trying to create a function in MATLAB:

It simulates a random walk and I want to count the number of steps it took to reach a boundary point as specified by user from origin (0,0)
they will specify: (b,z)
b: is the x point on the boundary it reaches in conjunction with
z: as the y point on the boundary.

Currently it is stopping after it reaches either the b or z value, but I want both to be reached. for example: I want it to reach (3,3) but it will stop running after it reaches (3,1) thus only satisfying one of my constraints.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
function s= rw_selectpoint(b,z)
%%exit time for square

%%set up square 2bx2z
%%center of square =(0,0)
x=0;
y=0;

walk_num=0;

%%set up probabilities and loop 
while (abs(x)< b && abs(y)<z)

 r= rand();
if (r<=.25)
walk_num=walk_num+1;
x=x+1

elseif ((.25<r) && (r<=.5))
walk_num=walk_num+1;
x=x-1

elseif ((.5<r) && (r<=.75))
walk_num=walk_num+1;
y=y+1

else %(.75<r)    
walk_num=walk_num+1;
y=y-1
end

end
s=walk_num;
display (x)
display (y)
%display (s)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition for your while loop is a conjunction of two statements.

```
while (abs(x)< b && abs(y)<z)
```

Thus, if one of them is false, then the condition is not satisfied and the loop terminates.

Change the `&&` to `||` and your code should work properly.